# Same Origin Policy - Displaying Ads

Tags: javascript, ads, same-origin-policy

I've got a difficult problem with iframes, origins, ads and so on.

So I have just started a new website, [mockrs.com](http://mockrs.com), and I'm trying to place ads there to generate some revenue. My ad code looks like this:

```
<aside id="leftAd" class="adWrapper160x600">
    <div class="ad">          
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            cpxcenter_width = 160;    
            cpxcenter_height = 600;
        </script>
        <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="http://ads.cpxcenter.com/cpxcenter/showAd.php?nid=4&amp;zone=22607&amp;type=banner&amp;sid=18035&amp;pid=17900&amp;subid=">
        </script>
    </div>
</aside>
```

This code should render ads and it does, but they're just 'placeholder' ads. The real ads are not rendered because of an error. Chrome says this:

> Blocked a frame with origin "http://ads.cpxcenter.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://mockrs.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.
>   Blocked a frame with origin "http://mockrs.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://ads.cpxcenter.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.

I think it may be something related to Same Origin Policy, but I'm not really sure, because other external scripts execute without a problem and they can render iframes on my site (facebook renders its Like button and the ad provider renders the 'placeholder' ads).

What's more, sometimes Chrome shows two or three such errors and sometimes they don't show up at all. I'm insanely confused, could you help me guys?

Comment: *"I think it may be something related to Same Origin Policy"* It is. I think you must be embedding the ad script incorrectly. Talk with the folks at "cpxcenter.com" or whatever they are for instructions on doing it correctly. Ad sites know better than to *rely* on cross-domain access.

Comment: FYI, you can remove both the `language` (deprecated in the 90's) and `type` (unnecessary pretty much forever) attributes from your `script` tags. They're nothing but wasted space when the script content is JavaScript.

Comment: I know these are deprecated or useless but I have just copied that snippet from the ad provider and didn't wanted to change anything because this bug is just insane. My coworker has emailed them already and we're still waiting for a response. However, I hope someone may be able to help me sooner : )

Answer (score 0):

It is a "SOP" issue. But as far as I know, there are elegant ways to implement advertisments without facing this problem. Just in addition to T.J. Crowders advice to ask your ad broker for correct implementation, you might find this interesting:

http://code.google.com/p/browsersec/wiki/Part2#Life_outside_same-origin_rules